# How can I set an ajax variable equal to a php variable?

Tags: php, ajax, variables

I'm looking for some guidance on how if I have an already existing php variable, that is not a web element, just a string, how can I pass that as a variable to ajax?

here is a santized snippet of what I'm doing.

I want to be able to pass $my_php_var to ajax.

```
<?php
$my_php_var = "foo";
?>

$(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
    var my_php_var = $my_php_var;
    $.ajax({
       url:"directory/script.php"),
       method:"POST",
       data:{my_php_var:my_php_var},
       dataType:"text",
       success:function(data);
       {
            alert(data);
       }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, print it there inside another `PHP` tag:

```
<?php
$my_php_var = "foo";
?>

$(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"directory/script.php"),
       method:"POST",
       data:{my_php_var:<?=$my_php_var?>},
       dataType:"text",
       success:function(data);
       {
            alert(data);
       }
    })
```

Where `<?=$var?>` is short version of `<?php echo $var; ?>`.